# Using Object.keys() to get searchParams

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Considering the below:

```
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  console.log(searchParams.toString());

  console.log(typeof searchParams);

  console.log(Object.values(searchParams));
```

And passing the URL `http://localhost:3000/client-data?task=test`

This logs:

`task=test` (The string of the object, understandable)

`object` (We know it's of type object, and has some key value pairs from prior test)

`[]` (Why are we not getting any keys / values from Object.keys() etc?)

Comment: If you need the values, you can use `.values()` and iterate over that.

Comment: Instances of [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) can also have duplicate keys. The entries cannot always be losslessly converted to an object for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

> Why are we not getting any keys / values from Object.keys() etc?

The key/values of the search params are not exposed as own properties of the object instance. They *cannot* be. Consider the following

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams("a=1&get=2");

console.log(params.a);
console.log(params.get);

console.log(params.get("a"));
console.log(params.get("get"));
```

If `params.a` gave you the value `"1"`, then `params.get` should also give you `"2"`. Yet that means it would overwrite the `.get()` method. And if *that* were to happen, then `params.get("a")` would never work.